# Wild card search in WiX

Tags: wix

If possible, I would like to do a wild card search for a directory in WiX.

I intend to use the `DirectorySearch` element to find a directory that will have slight name variations. For example, the directory could be named `Desktop10.0`, `Desktop10.1`, or `Desktop10.2`.

I have looked at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937674/wix-detecting-the-presence-of-a-directory-at-install-time) that looks for a more hardened name, [and another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519076/wix-check-file-exists-before-install) that recommends custom code. Before I go down one of these paths does anyone know a way to determine this variable named directory strictly in WiX?

Comment: If you can rely on finding the directory name in the registry, you can nest a registry search inside a directory search.

Comment: I ended up using the custom code approach. Not as elegant as I was striving for, but I got it working so I could move on.